# I2P Reseed servers

Tags: kovri, i2p

What is a reseed server ?

There is this [hard-coded list](https://github.com/monero-project/kovri/blob/master/src/client/reseed.h#L114) of url. Who are they ? Where does this list come from ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are seed nodes. Monero has them, and Bitcoin has them, etc.. Nothing unusual.

Monero seed nodes:

- https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/f4e2539a322c584c9b45ad5a000cb63e9e90aaab/src/p2p/net_node.h#L130

Bitcoin seed nodes:

- https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/1b2460bd5824170ab85757e35f81197199cce9d6/src/chainparams.cpp#L112

Java I2P seed nodes:

- https://github.com/i2p/i2p.i2p/blob/master/router/java/src/net/i2p/router/networkdb/reseed/Reseeder.java#L106

When you connect to Monero, I2P, or Bitcoin network, you must somehow find peers. The seed node is the starting point.