# I2P: How does the reseed works ?

Tags: kovri, i2p

I saw in [this question](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/3659/i2p-reseed-servers) that there are hard coded reseed servers.

How does it work exactly ?

Answer (score 7):

Indeed, the question cited refers to a list of url. The reseed process starts with choosing randomly one of them.

So let's assume that the choosen URL is : https://i2p.mooo.com/netDb/.
Here are the next steps :

- Download an [SU3](https://geti2p.net/spec/updates) file, which **must** be named [i2pseeds.su3](https://github.com/monero-project/kovri/blob/master/src/client/reseed.h#L111) and located at the root :

  ```
  curl -k -A "Wget/1.11.4" https://i2p.mooo.com/netDb/i2pseeds.su3 > i2pseeds.su3
  ```
- Check Signature and type:

  ```
  java -jar lib/i2p.jar su3file showversion i2pseeds.su3
  ```

  Or

  ```
  kovri-util su3file showversion i2pseeds.su3
  ```
- Extract the included file :

  ```
  java -jar lib/i2p.jar su3file extract i2pseeds.su3 i2pseeds.zip
  ```

  Or

  ```
   kovri-util su3file extract i2pseeds.su3 i2pseeds.zip
  ```
- Unzip :

  ```
   mkdir tmp && cd tmp && unzip ../i2pseeds.zip
  ```

At this point, you should see a list of files whose name looks like    `routerInfo-(44 character base 64 router hash).dat`

Each file can be inspected with :

```
kovri-util routerinfo <filename>
```

Or

```
java -jar lib/router.jar routerinfo <filename>
```

These are the informations needed to start contacting other peers in the I2P network.